# SQL UPDATE on a JOIN of two tables n:n

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

I need to do an Update query on the result of 2 table join. These 2 tables are in a n:n relationship. Here's the tables:

Table 1:

```
*CITIES*   [this is the table name] 
idcities (primary key)
cityname
```

Relationship tab:

```
*USER_HAS_CITIES*   [this is the table name] 
user_iduser (foreign key) 
cities_idcities (foreign key)
```

Table 2:

```
*USER*    [this is the table name] 
iduser (primary key) 
username 
password 
name 
surname
```

For example, I need to update the "cityname" (setting it to Los Angeles) where `user.iduser = 1 and cities.idcities = 2;`

How can I do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are actually using.  MySQL and SQL Server are different products.

Comment: Are you sure that you want change city name with filter by `user.iduser = 1`. I think you should update city name only by `cities.idcities = 2`

Comment: You are proposing to update only one table (`cities`).  This may change the some of the rows resulting from joining `cities` to `users` via `user_has_cities`, but it is not well described as an "update on a join".

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.cityname = 'Los Angeles'
FROM CITIES c
INNER JOIN USER_HAS_CITIES u ON u.ities_idcities = c.idcities
WHERE c.idcities = 2 AND u.iduser = 1
```

In MySQL:

```
UPDATE CITIES c
INNER JOIN USER_HAS_CITIES u ON u.ities_idcities = c.idcities AND c.idcities = 2 AND u.iduser = 1
SET c.cityname = 'Los Angeles'
```

Comment: The join to user_has_cities is really pointless here unless they only want to change the name of the city if that particular user has that city. Something is missing from the explanation from the OP for sure.

Comment: Joins can be faster than in statements or correlated subqueries.  Where exists is also usually faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear, but we've got a brand new stack overflow member asking it, so I'm going to try to make some assumptions and see if I can lead them to an answer.

First, if you have a `cities` table, it doesn't make much sense to update the city name. Just add or remove records from the list as needed. If you must update the name, it doesn't take a join. Simply:

```
update cities set cityname = 'Los Angeles' where id = 2;
```

The same is true of the `users` table. Don't use a join, just:

```
update users set pwd = '1234' where id = 4;
```

The only table that merits an update for this question is the `user_has_cities` table.

So let's assume that your `user_has_cities` table has a many:many relationship, that is there are many users, and each has many cities like in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f146b

If you know the id of the city and the user, you can do a simple update: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a420/1

```
update user_has_cities
set idcities = 1
where iduser = 5
and idcities = 6;
```

If you don't know the id of the city, but just the name, you could put a `select` in your `set` clause like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1f3/1

```
update user_has_cities
set idcities = (
  select id from cities where cityname = 'Los Angeles' limit 1
  )
where iduser = 5
and idcities = 6;
```

Make sure to limit the records returned, or you'll get an error if more than one city has the name 'Los Angeles'. This is pretty sketchy code anyway; it's much better to do your updates using a unique ID.

If you don't know the id of the current city, you could theoretically expand on the theme like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b28876/1

```
update user_has_cities
set idcities = (
  select id from cities where cityname = 'Los Angeles' limit 1
  )
where iduser = 5
and idcities in (select id from cities where cityname = 'Huntington Beach');
```

I don't claim to understand the question, so I don't know if this answers it, but I hope it helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of which DBMS you are using this would be accomplished like this.

```
update USER_HAS_CITIES
set cities_idcities = (select idcities from CITIES where cityname = 'Los Angeles')
where user_iduser = 1
```

Comment: you forgot`cities.idcities = 2`

Comment: the OP is asking for cityname to be updated.  your query updates cities_idcities

Comment: Right but if that is what they are really after it doesn't matter what userid it is, just a simple update to the cities table would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually propose to update only one table, you don't need any special sauce:

```
UPDATE cities
SET cityname = 'Los Angeles'
WHERE idcities = 2
```

If you want to condition the update on whether the given city is related to the given user, then you could add an appropriate condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM user_has_cities WHERE user_iduser = 1 AND cities_idcities = 2)
```

If you want to update the name of a given user's city(-ies) based on user id, without knowing the city id, then you could do this:

```
UPDATE cities
SET cityname = 'Los Angeles'
WHERE idcities IN (
  SELECT cities_idcities FROM user_has_cities WHERE user_iduser = 1)
```